# Compiling Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I've compiled Qt from the source with options:

```
-release -no-script -no-webkit
```

Now I'm trying to compile qtCreator using this build but I'm getting error:

```
ld.exe cannot find lQtScript
```

How can I set Qt Creator configuration to be the same as Qt, that mean with

```
-release -no-script -no-webkit
```

Answer (score 2):

QtCreator needs QtScript. You could try doing a `make -k` (ignoring compilation errors) and hope enough of QtCreator works without QtScript, but I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using QtScript is mandatory to build Qt Creator. You must have it in you build of Qt.... This becomes more tricky with the latest version of Qt (5.6) as QtScript is now deprecated and not provided.
You need to retrieve it separatly and add it to Qt so that you can make the build of Qt Creator.
For myself i had re-used QtScript from Qt 5.5.

Hope that helps.

Regards